# How to format the code in Remix IDE?

Tags: solidity, remix, ide

Is there a way to format/beautify the code in the Remix IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2023 (and possibly earlier), you can format the code by right-clicking and selecting "Format Code".

You can also use the shortcut `Shift + Option + F`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to automatically format/beautify the code at this time.

However, [Remix is open source and has modules that anyone can add](https://github.com/ethereum/remix#remix-modules). If you want, you are able to create an uncompromising code formatter, like [Black for Python](https://github.com/python/black), that can be used as a Remix module.